# Unable to pass String value from one java class to other

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-activity

i am trying to send the value of string which is accessed from a spinner and send it to data helper class to run a query and insert value in another spinner which is running on another activity

Method inside class which fetches value of string

NewTask.java

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
        long arg3) {

     // On selecting a spinner item
     label = spinnerComp.getSelectedItem().toString(); //storing value of spinner in string label
     System.out.println("NewTask label="+label);

     toRetDeptString();   //it will call return string method


    // Showing selected spinner item
    Toast.makeText(spinnerComp.getContext(), "You selected: " + label,
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

now the return string method is which is also declared inside NewTask.java

```
    public String toRetDeptString() {
    System.out.println("NewTask String label="+label);
    return label;
  }
```

and now i am trying to access the value of label string dataHelper class which runs the query on basis of value inside the string label

Inside DataHelper.java 
and in that inside DatabaseHelper class

```
    public List<String> getAllLabelsDept(){

           NewTask a = new NewTask();
           String n1= a.toRetDeptString();  //this one doesn't worked

               // String n1 = a.label;  //this one doesn't worked

         //  String n1="umbrella";  //this method worked by directly assiging string value
           System.out.println("a="+n1);
            List<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();


            //  Query
            String selectQuery = "select  " + Dept + " from "+TABLE_NAME +" where " + Comp + " = '" + n1 +"'";

            SQLiteDatabase db1 = this.getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = db1.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

            // looping through all rows and adding to list
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    labels.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Dept)));
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }

            // closing connection
            cursor.close();
            db1.close();

            // returning lables
            return labels;
        }
```

Select_Dept.java

```
  public class Select_Dept extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener{
Spinner spinnerDept;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_select__dept);

    spinnerDept = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerDept);
    spinnerDept.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    loadSpinnerDataDept();
}

private void loadSpinnerDataDept() {
    // database handler
    DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());

    // Spinner Drop down elements
    List<String> lables = db.getAllLabelsDept();

    // Creating adapter for spinner
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lables);

    // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
    dataAdapter
            .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    // attaching data adapter to spinner
    spinnerDept.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
        long arg3) {

     // On selecting a spinner item
     String label = spinnerDept.getSelectedItem().toString();

    // Showing selected spinner item
    Toast.makeText(spinnerDept.getContext(), "You selected: " + label,
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.select__dept, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

 }
```

output of Logcat:-

```
 - 06-05 12:30:13.369: I/ActivityManager(59): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.EzyCloud.ezytask/.MainActivity }
 - 06-05 12:30:14.160: I/ActivityManager(59): Displayed activity com.EzyCloud.ezytask/.MainActivity: 562 ms (total 562 ms)
06-05 12:30:16.139: I/ActivityManager(59): Starting activity: Intent { cmp=com.EzyCloud.ezytask/.NewTask }
 - 06-05 12:30:16.299: I/System.out(280): NewTask label=umbrella
 - 06-05 12:30:16.299: I/System.out(280): NewTask String label=umbrella
 - 06-05 12:30:16.559: I/ActivityManager(59): Displayed activity com.EzyCloud.ezytask/.NewTask: 406 ms (total 406 ms)
 - 06-05 12:30:19.140: I/ActivityManager(59): Starting activity: Intent { cmp=com.EzyCloud.ezytask/.Select_Dept }
 - 06-05 12:30:19.339: I/System.out(280): NewTask String label= //no value accesed
 - 06-05 12:30:19.339: I/System.out(280): a=                     **//no value accesed**
 - 06-05 12:30:19.699: I/ActivityManager(59): Displayed activity  - com.EzyCloud.ezytask/.Select_Dept: 508 ms (total 508 ms)
 - 06-05 12:30:24.849: D/dalvikvm(128): GC_EXPLICIT freed 202 objects / 9800 bytes in 145ms
```

but due to some problems value of string is not accesed

Comment: public String toRetDeptString() {
    System.out.println("NewTask String label="+label);
    return label;
  }, in this what is `label`?

Comment: label is a string which is declared at starting of class NewTask

Comment: please show the code for `Select_Dept`

Comment: I couldn't get your question, I will try to answer. Change `toRetDeptString();` to `toRetDeptString(label);` and `public String toRetDeptString() { System.out.println("NewTask String label="+label); return label; }` to public String toRetDeptString(String str) { System.out.println("NewTask String label="+str); return str; }`

Comment: I think issue might be that you are creating a new object of class- NewTask in DataHelper.java and you might need to use the same instance of it which has the value of string. Problem might be using the wrong instance of NewTask class

Comment: Why don't you make that `label` as `static` variable?

Comment: thanks Aniruddha making it static worked

Comment: Be aware that making it static means there will only ever be the one copy of label.  Don't be surprised when all instances of it's class share that one copy.  If one instance changes label, they all change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First ,when you get "System.out(280): NewTask String label= //no value accesed" ,the NewTask instance didn't in stack top .
Second ,the variable label is a private variable ,so it is possible not exist.

If you want to get label ,you could use "static" ,example "public static label ; " ,but i don't suggest for you to do like this, because this is dangerous .

Finally , you could build a customize Application class and "private String label ;" **strong text**to record the label(overall) or pass the label through intent.

Answer (score 2):

In `NewTask.java`, You are calling the `toRetDeptString()` within its own scope as default object.

In `DataHelper.java`, You are creating a new object and just calling the method. So obviously the string would be empty.

To pass string data to another activity, you can try using [intents](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidIntent/article.html) .
Or else, you would have to set the value to the model object and pass the object reference itself to the next activity instead of creating a new object and accessing the method.

Answer (score 0):

You can't share data across intents by simply using the same field unfortunately.

One way of dealing with this situation is to use a global singleton class to hold your values.

The other is to pass data around in bundles, as per below.

In the activity of spinner A create an intent:

```
/* Instead of FromActivity.this you can also use getApplicationContext() */
Intent intent = new Intent(FromActivity.this, ToActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("label", label);
startActivity(intent);
```

Then in the other spinner's activity you can retrieve them:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
if (extras !=null) {
    String value = extras.getString("label");
}
System.out.println("NewTask label = " + label);
```

Note that passing values via this method has some data size limitations, but in your particular case should work.

I don't claim that the exact same code would work in your application, but the concept itself should.

[Further reading](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)

Hope it helps.

Comment: on what do you base this assumption?  It is obvious based upon `onItemSelected` that label is a field

Comment: then how to retrieve the value in datahelper class

Comment: Fair enough, I've missed something very obvious. However, I have now taken my required coffee intake and revised my answer. I hope it helps.